# Lightning app builder, layout components side by side

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

I am trying to customize a layout for some lightning components, so that some are side by side, while others take up the entire pane in a custom tab

it seems like dragging and dropping always takes up the entire pane

is there a way that I can , within a custom tab, have a layout that allows side by side lightning components on one portion, and full pane lightning components on others?

here is an example of what I'm trying to accomplish

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about Lighning components inside Lightning Record Page?

Comment: not sure (new at this) in lightning when i click edit  page, a UI comes up where i can drag and drop, maybe thats a lightning record page?

Comment: Yes it is ! These pages have two sides. The left one is the main size so it's bigger. So you can put your components side by side. Except that the right one will be smaller.

Comment: i attempt to drag into the custom tab part of the page layout and it will not allow me to put components side by side, is there some trick?

Comment: The only way you can achieve this today is if you create and expose a new custom lightning component that wraps and styles the two components you want side by side.

Comment: I agree this is very useful. Vote for this idea to get this on the roadmap:  https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003UhVQAU

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Today this is not possible to do in the app builder.

In the app-builder you can add components only one below another, you cannot add components one beside another ,unless the template allows you to - the default template has a wide component area at the top, and below there are 2 areas - on the left the is a wider area and on the right there is a narrow area. you can select a different template, but inside each template, you can add components only one below another!!!

[image: The default object template]

Though side by side components is possible to accomplish if you create a lightning component in development (not the app builder D&D interface) and use [LIGHTNING DESIGN SYSTEM](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/) to arrange your components as you like.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, by changing the Template :

[image]

Best Regards!
Gaya

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE). Thank you for contributing. You answer does not exactly address the part of the original question from his illustration which is having a container with multiple columns of components *above* a container with a single column of components. Your answer gives another "workaround" If what the OP is requesting still cannot be done. Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/356960/edit) your answer to make it obvious that - although helpful - this is a workaround.